# Variation in keras and mlmodel results

Tags: python, keras, coremltools, onnx

I made a keras model for next word prediction. When i exported it to mlmodel and used it for text prediction, the results of the keras and the mlmodel varied. I used to Netron to visualize the model. I realized that the weights of some layers have changed during the conversion. But I had referred the official coreml documentation for this. Can you help me with this issue?. Thanks in advance.

When I saw difference in weights and predictions, I tried using onnx to convert the keras to onnx and onnx to mlmodel. But there was this error: "Unsupported ONNX ops of type: Cast,Gather,Shape,Identity" while converting the onnx model to mlmodel.

This is my LSTM model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, 10, input_length=max_length-1))
model.add(LSTM(100, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(50))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax'))
print(model.summary())
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', 
 metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X, y, epochs=100, verbose=2)
```

The prediction function:

```
def generate_seq(model, tokenizer, seq_length, seed_text, n_words):
 result = list()
 #n_words is the number of predictions I want
 in_text = seed_text
 # generate a fixed number of words
 for _ in range(n_words):
    # encode the text as integer
    encoded = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([in_text])[0]
    # truncate sequences to a fixed length
    encoded = pad_sequences([encoded], maxlen=seq_length, truncating='pre')
    y_prob=model.predict(encoded)

            #sort out the top n_words in order of the highest prob
    top_indices = y_prob.argsort()[0][-n_words:][::-1]


    # map predicted word index to word
    out_word = ''
    for top_index in top_indices:
        for word, index in tokenizer.word_index.items():
            if index == top_index:
                out_word+= word+' '
                        break

 return out_word
```

The keras to coreml conversion code:

```
from keras.models import load_model
import coremltools

model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert("model_train.h5")
model.save("model_train.mlmodel")
```

The results are totally variant. For e.g: For the input: "I read",the keras model predicts "it,book,this" whereas the mlmodel predicts "thought,had,was".

These are the weights of the embedding layer of my keras and mlmodel.
[Keras Model](https://www.filehosting.org/file/details/820874/weightsKerasModel.npy)
[ML Model](https://www.filehosting.org/file/details/820875/weightsMLMODEL.npy)